# Finding Minimums of all rows in a column, based on criteria, Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello Stackoverflow community!

I have attemped to find an answer to my question but without success. I am basically trying to replicate the MinIF formula from excel, but so far I have only managed to do it for "1" row at a time. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[Please see attached link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh1L3.png)

The idea is, that for all products with the same subgroup, the lowest value/price for that group is found, and inserted in a new column next to it.
I hope i am being specific enough, I am relatively new to python, and I have literally no idea how to even start...

help much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['SubGroupLowestPrice'] = df.groupby('SubGroup')['Price'].transform('min')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,5],
                   'SubGroup':[1,5,5,6,6,6],
                   'Price':[7,8,9,10,2,3]})

print (df)
   A  Price  SubGroup
0  1      7         1
1  2      8         5
2  3      9         5
3  4     10         6
4  5      2         6
5  5      3         6

df['SubGroupLowestPrice'] = df.groupby('SubGroup')['Price'].transform('min')
print (df)
   A  Price  SubGroup  SubGroupLowestPrice
0  1      7         1                    7
1  2      8         5                    8
2  3      9         5                    8
3  4     10         6                    2
4  5      2         6                    2
5  5      3         6                    2
```